# 'find' command misbehaving with *.jpg files?

Tags: bash, macos, quoting, glob

If I issue this find command, it only shows what is in the specified directory:

```
find /Users/me/Pictures -name *.jpg
```

but if I issue this one, it traverses the sub-folders and shows me all the .NEF files:

```
find /Users/me/Pictures -name *.NEF
```

There are lots of .jpg files in the sub-folders. What is going on?

Thanks.

Update: 
I deleted that single .jpg file and then the command worked and found the rest of them. Seriously? What just happened?

Comment: Try `-name '*.jpg'`.

Answer (score 1):

> Seriously? What just happened?

You have just learned about shell wildcard expansion.

When you enter an unquoted wildcard (`*`) on the command line, that is expanded *by the shell* before the command line executes.  So if you have a files in your local directory named `foo.jpg` and `bar.jpg`, then:

```
echo *.jpg
```

Expands into:

```
echo foo.jpg bar.jpg
```

And you will see as output:

```
foo.jpg bar.jpg
```

But if you have *no matching files*, then the commandline is run verbatim and you will see as output:

```
*.jpg
```

This is exactly what happened to your `find` command.  With a single `.jpg` in your current directory, `*.jpg` expanded to the name of the file.  Once you removed the file, the `*.jpg` expression was preserved and passed on to the `find` command.

The solution, as indicated in the comments, is to quote your arguments to find `find` command to inhibit shell wildcard expansion. Even with files `foo.jpg` and `bar.jpg` in your directory, if you run:

```
echo "*.jpg"
```

You will see as output:

```
*.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that with `find /Users/me/Pictures -name *.jpg` is that the shell (Bash) expands the `*.jpg` before the command is executed. So if you have a folder like this:

```
$ ls
1.jpg  2.jpg  3.jpg  dir1  dir2  dir3
```

the shell expands `*.jpg` by applying the regex. So the command that will be issued to the prompt after will be `find /Users/me/Pictures -name 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg`. (This command actually fails for me on Linux, so macOS seems to behave differently).

If you surround the `*.jpg` with quotes, like Daniel suggested, the expression will not be expanded/"globbed".

Answer (score 0):

try using double quotes with expressions and let us know how it goes.

```
find /Users/me/Pictures -name "*.NEF"
OR
find /Users/me/Pictures -name "*.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if extensions are .jpg or .JPG! Many times we ignore capital case in extension.

Best thing is try ignore case and put `*.jpg` in double quote

```
find ./ -iname "*.jpg"
```